# Confusion in a problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, work

This is a very basic homework type question. I guess there is some intermixing of concepts in my head. Help.

There was a question I came across -

A ball of mass 0.2 kg is thrown vertically upwards by applying a force by hand. If the hand moves 0.2 m which applying the force and the ball goes upto 2 m height further, find the magnitude of the force. Consider $g=10 m/s^2$.

There are two possible answers for this question.
Let velocity after the hand has released the ball be v

$$v^2 = 4g$$ **(since s = 2, m and a = g)**

Now, the force applied by the hand cause the ball to accelerate to this velocity from rest.

Let acceleration caused by force be a.
=>
$$v^2 = 0 + 2*0.2*a$$

=>

40 = 0.4 a

a= 100
Here is where I am confused.

=> $F = m * a = 0.2 * 100 = 20 N$

OR

Cause the acceleration is provided against acceleration
  F = m*(a+g) = 0.2 * (110) = 22 N.

**Which one is correct? Why?** 
 I guess it is 22 N. On solving by energy conservation we get 22 N.

Comment: Could you think of a more descriptive title please?

Answer (score 2):

The work done by you when you apply a force on the ball does two things:
It increases the gravitational potential energy of the ball up to the point of release.
It increases the kinetic energy of the ball up to the point of release. 
This is you energy method.

In terms of forces if you just lifted the ball and it had no kinetic energy at the end what force would you have to apply - a force equal in magnitude to the weight of the ball.
You need an extra force to accelerate the ball so that it was an upward velocity at the point of release.

In terms of the constant acceleration kinematic equations the motion after release enables you to find the release velocity.

Knowing the velocity at the point of release and assuming the ball starts from rest the kinematic equations give you the acceleration during this phase.
Using N2L you now find the force needed to produce this acceleration.
This is the net force acting on the ball and as you know the weight of the ball you can find the force exerted by the hand on the ball.